# My simple enable and disable account powershell code doesnt work right

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check a local user account if its either disabled or enabled and do the following:
If enabled tell me "account is enabled, nothing to do"

If the account is disabled, tell me, Account is disabled, enabling...
Enabled the account

What I get is always the first output no matter if the account is disabled or enabled:

```
#Checks local  user if its disabled to enable it
$isEnabled = $True
$Account = 'local_account'

try {
    $isEnabled = (Get-LocalUser $Account -ErrorAction Stop).Disabled
    Write-output  "local_account account is already enabled" 
}

catch {
    $isEnabled = $False
    write-output "local_account account is disabled, enabling..."
    Enable-LocalUser $Account
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `.Disabled` property on those objects, you need to check for `.Enabled` instead. You're also missing an [`if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3).

```
try {
    $Account = 'local_account'

    # if its enabled
    if((Get-LocalUser $Account -ErrorAction Stop).Enabled) {
        "$Account account is already enabled"
    }
    else {
        # if its not enabled
        "$Account account is disabled, enabling..."
        Enable-LocalUser $Account -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch {
    # if there was an error while enabling or trying to find the account
    Write-Error $_
}
```

Comment: Hi This works really well, however and this is my fault as I didnt mention it. I have to add this code to a larger script. So I have to take out the "return" code so the script doesnt exit early. I replaced it with "write-output but now it gives me both ouputs even if the account is already enabled:

Comment: @Drekko I see, an `if / else` would make sense in this case then. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

#### See the rewritten script below

- **Main culprit** `.Disabled` is not a property of `Get-LocalUser` use `.Enabled` instead
- You have a missing `}` for your catch block, assuming copy/paste error
- The `$isEnabled` variable has been removed because it is not used in the script.
- The `Get-LocalUser` cmdlet is called with the -Name parameter instead of the `$Account` variable. This is a best practice because it is more clear and concise.
- The if statement has been used to check whether the account is disabled instead of setting the `$isEnabled` variable to True or False. This is a more concise way to check the account status.
- The `Write-Output` cmdlet is used instead of `write-output`. This is a best practice because it is more consistent with PowerShell's naming conventions.
- The `Write-Error` cmdlet is used to display errors. This is a best practice because it formats the error message in a way that makes it easy to identify the source of the error.

```
$Account = 'local_account'

try {
    $User = Get-LocalUser -Name $Account -ErrorAction Stop
    if (-NOT $User.Enabled) {
        Write-Output "The '$Account' account is disabled. Enabling..."
        $User | Enable-LocalUser
        Write-Output "The '$Account' account has been enabled."
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "The '$Account' account is already enabled."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred while checking the status of the '$Account' account. Details: $_"
}
```